# CSS - ignore padding from parent (no negative margin)

Tags: css, padding

I'm trying to figure out how to ignore padding set by a parent element.

I have created a sample code here to play with:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

img {
  padding: unset;
}

.details {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">


  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus aliquam nisi, eget gravida dolor. Maecenas id pretium urna. Maecenas eu odio eu mauris tristique iaculis. Mauris posuere turpis arcu, et viverra erat laoreet sed. Nulla in faucibus
  lorem. Phasellus ultricies rhoncus urna, vitae sodales eros varius vitae. Fusce vitae diam elit. In imperdiet arcu in mauris tincidunt, in aliquam elit sollicitudin. Etiam malesuada, libero id dictum congue, urna ligula vestibulum turpis, pellentesque
  auctor dolor nulla semper enim. Sed non neque sit amet tortor blandit malesuada. Mauris dapibus congue volutpat. Mauris sit amet tortor vel tortor lacinia lobortis. Morbi scelerisque mauris ac condimentum aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur commodo urna at nisi malesuada malesuada. Vestibulum eu neque nec orci porta pharetra eu nec enim. Phasellus a cursus lacus, at tristique magna. Vivamus venenatis est non magna pretium
  ornare. Pellentesque molestie malesuada finibus. Nam pretium elementum est, scelerisque dignissim sapien bibendum non. Nunc id ex at elit consequat convallis a eget tellus. Fusce quis auctor arcu. Phasellus id mauris tincidunt, vulputate neque nec,
  aliquam erat. Maecenas feugiat porta porttitor. Donec ut ex tempor nisi feugiat rutrum. Praesent auctor, justo sit amet facilisis pretium, sem mi accumsan ante, tristique pretium arcu felis id risus. Vestibulum ac orci justo.

  <table class="details">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Ut mollis justo non condimentum venenatis. Pellentesque et mi vel lectus consequat laoreet in eu risus. Cras elementum fermentum pretium. Nullam laoreet sed neque ut mattis. Pellentesque condimentum mi vel sapien mattis, ac porta libero gravida. Maecenas
  non erat at ligula ultrices bibendum. Quisque neque est, commodo eget orci nec, congue pretium lorem.

  <img class="test" src="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2020/02/huawei-gt-active-top-scaled.jpg" width="100%"> Aenean ultrices posuere rutrum. Vivamus scelerisque leo a velit faucibus, sed congue massa condimentum. Nam bibendum leo in arcu aliquet
  laoreet. Duis vulputate quam vel euismod volutpat. Sed commodo, nibh at aliquet porttitor, leo ante varius massa, in ultrices enim turpis et metus. Morbi fermentum neque est, at consectetur purus elementum ut. Aliquam dictum pretium tristique. Suspendisse
  ullamcorper interdum libero sed tempor. Praesent vulputate sapien venenatis dui feugiat aliquet. Sed consectetur mi sit amet arcu iaculis dapibus. Vestibulum ac est eu urna laoreet fermentum et eget quam.
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have padding on everything but images and tables. The image and the table should occupy all the available space, it should touch the left and right border. This is why I can't use negative margin as it would simply shift the image or the table to the left.

I have also tried negative margin and extending the image width with calc(100% + xxpx) but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea of how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could try img { padding: unset; } after your content class or img { padding: 0; }

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this too (and updated the codepen) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I might know, what you are looking for now

Comment: `.content:not(img)` well yeah your element with class `content` is not an image so its applying the style, its the expected output. You will have to wrap your text in a wrapper element and target that with padding

Comment: @ImmortalDude, thanks, that's what I'm trying to avoid because it would add a lot of code, I have a lot of text alternating with images.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Your codepen is working correctly for me?

Comment: @BrettParsons he's edting the codepen with my answer, that's why ..

Comment: I know.  He said that the calc didn't work, but it definitely does.

Comment: #Brett, yes I tried and it didn't work but I now understand why, I had a overflow hidden property somewhere that was hiding the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

negative margin works fine if you correctly set the width:

```css
.content {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid;
}

table {
  margin: 0 -50px;
  width:calc(100% + 100px);
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

img {
  margin: 0 -50px;
  display: block;
  width:auto;
  max-width:calc(100% + 100px);
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus aliquam nisi, eget gravida dolor. Maecenas id pretium urna. Maecenas eu odio eu mauris tristique iaculis. Mauris posuere turpis arcu, et viverra erat laoreet sed. Nulla in faucibus
  lorem. Phasellus ultricies rhoncus urna, vitae sodales eros varius vitae. Fusce vitae diam elit. In imperdiet arcu in mauris tincidunt, in aliquam elit sollicitudin. Etiam malesuada, libero id dictum congue, urna ligula vestibulum turpis, pellentesque
  auctor dolor nulla semper enim. Sed non neque sit amet tortor blandit malesuada. Mauris dapibus congue volutpat. Mauris sit amet tortor vel tortor lacinia lobortis. Morbi scelerisque mauris ac condimentum aliquam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur commodo urna at nisi malesuada malesuada. Vestibulum eu neque nec orci porta pharetra eu nec enim. Phasellus a cursus lacus, at tristique magna. Vivamus venenatis est non magna pretium
  ornare. Pellentesque molestie malesuada finibus. Nam pretium elementum est, scelerisque dignissim sapien bibendum non. Nunc id ex at elit consequat convallis a eget tellus. Fusce quis auctor arcu. Phasellus id mauris tincidunt, vulputate neque nec,
  aliquam erat. Maecenas feugiat porta porttitor. Donec ut ex tempor nisi feugiat rutrum. Praesent auctor, justo sit amet facilisis pretium, sem mi accumsan ante, tristique pretium arcu felis id risus. Vestibulum ac orci justo.

  <table class="details">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Ut mollis justo non condimentum venenatis. Pellentesque et mi vel lectus consequat laoreet in eu risus. Cras elementum fermentum pretium. Nullam laoreet sed neque ut mattis. Pellentesque condimentum mi vel sapien mattis, ac porta libero gravida. Maecenas
  non erat at ligula ultrices bibendum. Quisque neque est, commodo eget orci nec, congue pretium lorem.
  <img class="test" src="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2020/02/huawei-gt-active-top-scaled.jpg" width="100%">
  Ut mollis justo non condimentum venenatis. Pellentesque et mi vel lectus consequat laoreet in eu risus. Cras elementum fermentum pretium. Nullam laoreet sed neque ut mattis. Pellentesque condimentum mi vel sapien mattis, ac porta libero gravida. Maecenas
  non erat at ligula ultrices bibendum. Quisque neque est, commodo eget orci nec, congue pretium lorem.

</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this was what I was looking for. I had somehow already tried this but it didn't work because I had left a overflow:hidden somewhere in my code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you have your image embedded in your div, and without some tricky css you won't get what you are looking for

```
<div class="content">
   ...
</div>
<img class="test" src="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2020/02/huawei-gt-active-top-scaled.jpg" width="100%"> 
<div class="content">
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
</div>
```